# Javascript Loop Restrict to only 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using:

```
$.each(data.mydata, function(index, value){
  output += '<li>'+value.title+'</li>';
}
```

I need to test something and only want the loop to get 1 off the list.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Is `data.mydata` an object or an array?

Comment: what about `output += '<li>'+data.mydata[0].title+'</li>';`? I don't see the need for a loop if you're only getting one element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Break it in the callback by returning false.

```
$.each(data.mydata, function(index, value){
  output += '<li>'+value.title+'</li>';
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

So adding `return false` after your logic would have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a for loop then

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  output += '<li>'+data.mydata[i].title+'</li>';
}
```

Or no loop at all really

```
if(data.mydata.length > 0)
    output += '<li>'+data.mydata[i].title+'</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping if you want one?

```
var myData = data.mydata;
var firstItem = myData[0];
var firstTitle = firstItem.title;
```

all in one line

```
var firstTitle = data.mydata[0].title;
```

Comment: I only wanted 1 to check something out...but would normally loop.